# Ember Query store asap in component lifecycle

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm playing with making a drag and drop UI. Each **person** has a component that can be dragged into a position, and a reference to that position is saved in an associated **position** model. Multiple different **positions** will be posible, so it needs to be a seperate model.

As each **person** component is created, I want query the store to find the certain **position**, and then use this to set the absolute position of the component on the page.

I've tried querying the store to find the certain **posiiton** during the different [lifecycle hooks](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.5.0/components/the-component-lifecycle/), but the store doesn't seem to be available. When and where might it be possible to do this?

My other thought is that I should perhaps find the certain **position** for each student in the route's controller, and then pass these into the component, but I would really prefer to keep as much as possible within the component.

Comment: You shouldnt be doing position related things in component since it's the callers (controller in this case) must to resolve promises etc. So resolve and sortBy('order') in controller and then just bind it to component. Hard 2 give any exact answer without seeing any code but i've exact same thing going on (drag drop area left) elements on the right. Order saved for each object and then standardized in the edit contorller before added to component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, accessing the store in a component isn't encouraged, but you can definitely do it. The `store` is a service, so you can inject it in components. To do so, you need to create an initializer like this:

```
export function initialize(application) {
  application.inject('component', 'store', 'service:store');
}

export default {
  name: 'component-injections',
  after: 'ember-data',
  initialize: initialize
};
```

With this, the store will be available in components, and you can utilize that however you'd like.

Comment: That's great, thanks. & @krsitjanreinhold I'll certainly have another think about whether there's a more "Ember" way to do things. I'll post an update when I figure out the (my) best solution.